# How to match a group of words that appear consecutively in any order?

Tags: python, regex

Say I have a group (or set) of words: {foo, bar, baz}, and I want to match and extract the group. The words can be in any order, but they need to be next to each other. For example,

```
hello foo bar baz wow yeah => foo bar baz
hello bar foo baz wow yeah => bar foo baz
wow yeah hello baz bar foo hello => baz bar foo
baz yeah bar foo hello => no match
```

What'd be a good regex, preferably Python, to accomplish this?

Comment: Can any of the words appear more than once?

Comment: The group can appear more than once, but each of the words within the group should only appear once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>If each word can only appear once (in the entire string), you may use:</s>

```
(?:\b(foo|bar|baz)(?!.*\b\1\b) ){3}
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/k5aJcN/1)**.

If words might repeat, I don't think you can get any shorter than something like this:<sup>*</sup>

```
\b(foo|bar|baz) (?!\1)(foo|bar|baz) (?!\1|\2)(foo|bar|baz)\b
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3fQ4kf/1)**.

**Details:**

- `\b` - Word boundary.
- `(foo|bar|baz)` - Match any of the specified words and capture it in group 1.
- `(?!\1)` - A space character not immediately followed by the word captured in group 1.
- `(foo|bar|baz)` - Match any of the specified words and capture it in group 2.
- `(?!\1|\2)` - A space char not immediately followed by any of the words previously captured.
- `(foo|bar|baz)` - Match any of the specified words and capture it in group 3.
- `\b` - Word boundary.

Note: The third occurrence of `foo|bar|baz` can be used without a capturing group (i.e., in a non-capturing group) but I left it there for consistency.

**Python example:**

```py
import re

regex = r"\b(foo|bar|baz) (?!\1)(foo|bar|baz) (?!\1|\2)(foo|bar|baz)\b"
test_str = """hello foo bar baz wow yeah
hello bar foo baz wow yeah
wow yeah hello baz bar foo hello
baz yeah bar foo hello"""

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)
for match in matches:
    print (match.group())
```

**Output:**

```
foo bar baz
bar foo baz
baz bar foo
```

**[Try it online](https://rextester.com/RZIOE82379)**.

---

<sup>*</sup> <sub>We can actually use a slightly shorter pattern for this specific case: `\b(foo|ba[rz]) (?!\1)(foo|ba[rz]) (?!\1|\2)(foo|ba[rz])\b` but that wouldn't work for any 3 words.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can use positive lookaheads to capture what's after 3 words and match each of the 3 desired words with a lookahead assertion that what was captured will follow:

```
(?=(\w+ \w+ \w+)(.*))(?=.*\bfoo\b.*\2)(?=.*\bbar\b.*\2)(?=.*\bbaz\b.*\2)
```

Each match can then be found in group #1.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/0tHKN5/2

EDIT: Performance improved from 5490 to 1377 steps according to regex101 with a word boundary assertion at the start and at most 2 words around each keyword instead of trying until the end with `.*`:

```
(?=(\b\w+ \w+ \w+)(.*))(?=(?:\w+ ){,2}\bfoo\b(?: \w+){,2}\2)(?=(?:\w+ ){,2}\bbar\b(?: \w+){,2}\2)(?=(?:\w+ ){,2}\bbaz\b(?: \w+){,2}\2)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/0tHKN5/3